# RecyclerView animation when clearing whole adapter and adding new elements

Tags: android, android-animation, android-recyclerview

So imagine that at first we load 10 items in our RecyclerView. Adding or removing one element gives us a nice animation (the adapter has stable ids).

The problem is, I have a search bar, I can look for something and then the result should replace the current items of the RecyclerView. If some item was already there, there is a nice "moving" animation. But if all items are new, there is a quite ugly fade-in transition that it's too fast and looks like a glitch. Is it possible to override that animation? I'd like to have a fade-out-fade-in one but slower.

By the way, when the query returns with results, I do this in the adapter:

```
mItems.clear();
mItems.addAll(resultItems);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Also, it's worth to say that if I make a search with no results, then I see the RecyclerView empty and then if I get some results again, the transition from empty state to some results looks ok.

Answer (score 1):

You can batch remove and insert items in a `RecyclerView`.

```
adapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, mItems.size());
mItems.clear();
mItems.addAll(resultItems);
adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, mItems.size());
```

EDIT: After looking at your problem some more you probably don't want to do what I suggested above. Instead you should not clear your list and instead remove some items and then notify the adapter of the change with `notifyItemRemove(index)`

Answer (score 0):

If you do range methods like RangeRemoved/RangeAdded, you loose out in the animation side. So, do it one by one in a loop to preserve the animation effect of one by one, including a delay in the loop. Here's how I have implemented:

**MainActivity.java**

```
clearItemsView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final List<LineItem> lineItemsCopy = new ArrayList<>(lineItems);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int i=0; i<lineItemsCopy.size(); i++) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                salesOrderItemListAdapter.removeItem(0);
                            }
                        });
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start();
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, getString(R.string.items_cleared_message), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction(getString(R.string.label_undo), new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    for (int i=0; i<lineItemsCopy.size(); i++) {
                                        final int finalI = i;
                                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                salesOrderItemListAdapter.restoreItem(lineItemsCopy.get(finalI), 0);
                                            }
                                        });
                                        try {
                                            Thread.sleep(500);
                                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }).start();
                        }
                    }).setActionTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            snackbar.show();
        }
    });
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
    //Only remove & restore functions are shown    
    public void removeItem(int position) {
        lineItems.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    public void restoreItem(LineItem item, int position) {
        lineItems.add(position, item);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }
```